# react-native: hot-loading on two devices simultaneously in development

Tags: react-native

I'm developing an app for both Android and iOS at the same time and I have my two phones in front of me. I have hot-loading enabled on both of them, but it seems only the last phone I touched will hot-load and the other one stays inactive until I shake it and choose "reload js" again.

Is this intended behaviour?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran into this issue too. 
You can get around it by running the packager on two separate ports. In my `package.json` I have:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start ",
  "port-8082": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start --port 8082",
},
```

And in my iOS startup code in `AppDelegate` I changed the port to 8082 e.g.

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8082/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

So then I run `npm start` in one terminal session (which starts on the default port 8081), and `npm run port-8082` in another session. Then 8081 will serve the Android device and 8082 the iOS device, and you can use Hot Reloading on both devices simultaneously.

**Edit**: With the change of react-native file architecture, the `AppDelegate` code is now:

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8082/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this method to debug both Android and iOS platforms at the same time:

1. Add `["port-8082": "react-native start --port 8082"]` in `package.json` under "scripts" section to launch another metro process to support Android platform. (You could input [npm run port-8082] to launch this metro process)
2. Using `[adb -s <DeviceName> reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8082`] to make Android device(port:8081) mapping to MacOS(`port:8082`).(You could use `[adb devices]` to find the `<DeviceName>` of Android Device)

Comment: `adb -s $(adb devices 2>&1 | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $1;}') reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8082`
- This one liner is for step 2. Given you are working on one android device (the other device would be iOS then) this command will help most of the time.